# Is there any way of discarding the changes made to master branch by mistake?

Tags: git, branch, local

Rather than making changes on local branch I have by mistake made those over to master branch itself, now master branch is saying that those changes needed to be committed, but I want to keep my master branch intact as it was before, so there any way of discarding those changes and get the message of saying 'working tree clean'.

Comment: Unstage the changes ? `git staus` guides you on how to do it

Comment: Stash them? Reset them? Checkout a different branch and commit them there?

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you please elloborate it more...

Comment: @jonrsharpe how about checkinng out to another branch and committing those changes to the same and after pushing it on master will that make master branch free from conflict by chacking git status

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *"pushing it on master"*, but if the changes are committed to another branch they won't be there when you check out master again.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thhanks for your prompt reply can you do me a favor! Is it possible for you to aceess my system and have it  a look for a better suggestion We can make some remote access arrengments.

Comment: No; the point of SO is that this information can help multiple users with similar problems, not for personal consulting.

Comment: @jonrsharpe please help me brother, after correct my problem you can help others as well

Comment: @jonrsharpe HI ...I eventually gathered guts and tried out the suggestions provided by you and it worked like a magic for me...I could resist my master branch back to normal and could save the work flow, for which I have been putting efforts for so long...thanking your apprecitiveness and compassion for replying us....it has really been an extra-ordinary help...thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

You want to set your branch to exactly match the remote branch ? Then do:

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```